# Start multiple countdown with jquery

Tags: jquery, countdown

I want to start multiple countdown on my site, but I don't understand why it's not OK can you help me ?

I get timer with each "data-tempsctrl"

In LoadCtrlfreq2.php:

```
<tr data-tempsctrl="0:00:35" class="color">
<td width="200px"><div class="countdown"></div>
</td>
<td width="150px"><button data-idctrl="50" data-result="ok" class="restartcount"> Conforme</button> <button data-idctrl="1" data-result="nok" class="restartnc"> non Conforme</button></td>
</tr>

<tr data-tempsctrl="0:00:55" class="color">
<td width="200px"><div class="countdown"></div>
</td>
<td width="150px"><button data-idctrl="50" data-result="ok" class="restartcount"> Conforme</button> <button data-idctrl="1" data-result="nok" class="restartnc"> non Conforme</button></td>
</tr>

<tr data-tempsctrl="0:01:35" class="color">
<td width="200px"><div class="countdown"></div>
</td>
<td width="150px"><button data-idctrl="50" data-result="ok" class="restartcount"> Conforme</button> <button data-idctrl="1" data-result="nok" class="restartnc"> non Conforme</button></td>
</tr>
```

Below function for display countdown for each timer
Page with javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){     

          $('[data-tempsctrl]').each(function() {
            startCountdown(this);
          });

        $('.restartcount').on('click', function(){  
        var action = "envoi";   
        var recfreq = '&action=' + action;

                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'LoadCtrlfreq2.php',
                        data:'ligne='+ligne,
                        success:function(html){
                            $('#acfreq').fadeIn("slow");
                            $('#acfreq').html(html);
                        }
                    }); 

        clearInterval(countdown);
        startCountdown();          });


          });
        </script>

    <div class="acfreq" id="acfreq"></div>
```

Comment: I forget the function startCountdown

Comment: function startCountdown (countdownRow) {
var $this = $(countdownRow);
var startTime = $this.data('tempsctrl');
var seconds = 0;
var timeTokens = startTime.split(':');
seconds += parseInt(timeTokens[0], 10) * 60 * 60;
seconds += parseInt(timeTokens[1], 10) * 60;
seconds += parseInt(timeTokens[2], 10);     
 var countdown = setInterval(function() {
   --seconds;              
if (seconds > 0) {

Comment: $this.find('.countdown').html('Prochain controle dans :'+
  formatTime(Math.floor(seconds / 3600)) +':'+ formatTime(Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60)) +':'+ formatTime(Math.floor(seconds % 60))
 );
          
} else {
$this.find('.countdown').html('');
$(".restartcount").blink();
clearInterval(countdown);
 }
}, 1000);
 $this.data('countdown', countdown);
 }

Comment: Could you update your question with the code from your comments?

Comment: I try, but doesn't works i have an error :s

Comment: You have an error when attempting to edit your question - or you have an error running your code?

Comment: When i edit question, i can't add any code